# Is their any way to make error Text align to textFormField border and their content inside with padding 16

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

[TextFormField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8i2e.png)
I want to make a custom text field with validation that has content padding of 16 px,
but the error Text aligns with the text field borders.

I wrote some code but was not able to achieve this text field.

can anyone help me to design a TextFormField like this in flutter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSm6h.png)
Thanks in advance

````
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final bool isPass, isReadOny, autoFocus;
  final String hintText;
  final TextInputType textInputType;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final bool isValidate;
  final Function(String)? validator;
  final int? maxLength;
  final List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;
  const MyTextField({
    Key? key,
    this.controller,
    this.isPass = false,
    this.isReadOny = false,
    this.autoFocus = false,
    required this.hintText,
    this.textInputType = TextInputType.text,
    this.onTap,
    this.isValidate = true,
    this.validator,
    this.maxLength,
    this.inputFormatters,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyTextField> createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  bool isObserver = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          controller: widget.controller,
          validator: (val) {
            if (widget.isValidate) {
              if (val!.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter ${widget.hintText}';
              } else {
                return widget.validator!(val);
              }
            }
          },
          style: GlobalFonts.ts20px700w(),
          readOnly: widget.isReadOny,
          autofocus: widget.autoFocus,
          cursorColor: greenColor,
          onTap: widget.onTap,
          maxLength: widget.maxLength,
          inputFormatters: widget.inputFormatters,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            counter: const Offstage(),
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
            hintText: widget.hintText,
            hintStyle: GlobalFonts.ts16px700w(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.5)),
            labelText: widget.hintText,
            labelStyle: GlobalFonts.ts16px700w(color: greenColor),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF166351), width: 1.5)),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF166351), width: 1.5)),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF166351), width: 1.5)),
            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFFF2B02), width: 1.5)),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            suffixIcon: widget.isPass
                ? IconButton(
                    icon: isObserver
                        ? const Icon(Icons.visibility_outlined,
                            color: greenColor, size: 20)
                        : const Icon(Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                            color: greenColor, size: 20),
                    onPressed: () => setState(
                      () => isObserver = !isObserver,
                    ),
                  )
                : null,
          ),
          keyboardType: widget.textInputType,
          obscureText: widget.isPass && !isObserver,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: You Want like this type TextFormField : [ https://www.linkpicture.com/view.php?img=LPic64c35609bd1d71070296598 ]

Comment: Yeah but the error text will aligned to border

Answer (score 0):

Try below custmotextformfield :

```
class CustomTextFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String labelText;
  final String hintText;

  CustomTextFormField({
    required this.controller,
    required this.labelText,
    required this.hintText,
  });

  @override
  _CustomTextFormFieldState createState() => _CustomTextFormFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFormFieldState extends State<CustomTextFormField> {
  bool _obscureText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      obscureText: _obscureText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: widget.labelText,
        hintText: widget.hintText,
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(_obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _obscureText = !_obscureText;
            });
          },
        ),
        errorText: "helloo",
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1.5),
        ),
        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter your password';
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}
```